# Pyspark is unable to find bigquery datasource

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery

This is my pyspark configuration. Ive followed the steps mentioned [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/issues/55) and didnt create a sparkcontext.

```
 spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName(appName) \
        .config(conf=spark_conf) \
        .config('spark.jars.packages', 'com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12:0.22.0') \
        .config('spark.jars.packages','com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcsio:1.5.4') \
        .config('spark.jars', 'gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar,spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12-0.21.1.jar,spark-bigquery-latest_2.11.jar') \
        .config('spark.jars', 'postgresql-42.2.23.jar,bigquery-connector-hadoop2-latest.jar') \
        .getOrCreate()
```

Then when i try to write a demo spark dataframe to bigquery

```
df.write.format('bigquery') \
        .mode(mode) \
        .option("credentialsFile", "creds.json") \
        .option('table', table) \
        .option("temporaryGcsBucket",bucket) \
        .save()
```

It throws and error

```
File "c:\sparktest\vnenv\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o60.save.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: bigquery. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

Comment: I think you are overriding `spark.jars.packages` and `spark.jars` configuration because it's calling twice. Also, if those JAR files are on GS, it might be necessary to put the absolute path to each file separated by comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was with faulty jar versions. I am using spark 3.1.2 and hadoop 3.2 this was the maven jars with code which worked for me.

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .master('local') \
    .appName('spark-read-from-bigquery') \
    .config('spark.jars.packages','com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12:0.22.0,com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcs-connector:hadoop3-1.9.5,com.google.guava:guava:r05') \
    .config('spark.jars','guava-11.0.1.jar,gcsio-1.9.0-javadoc.jar') \ # you will have to download these jars manually
    .getOrCreate()
```